# How to get value of a specific element in xml in c#

Tags: c#

I have a xml file in below format

I want to fetch the value of Child1
When I am using below code it is providing a null value. Please help

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
 XElement po = xmlDoc.Root.Element("Root");
 XElement el1 = po.Element("Child1");
```

Comment: Root should be allready the root tag.

Comment: BTW, the second `<Root>` should of course be `</Root>`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
xmlDoc.Descendants("Child1").First();
```

Comment: Or `xmlDoc.Descendants("Child1").First().Value` if you only want the value, or also `xmlDoc.Root.Element("Child1").Value`

Comment: i used below code as mentioned by you string s1 = xmlDoc.Root.Element("Child1").Value;i am getting error as Object reference not set to an instance of an object.